# nil в языках программирования

Tags: проектирование, любой-язык, null, типизация

Меня интересует как используется `nil` в различных языках программирования, и вообще насколько это удобно с точки зрения дизайна языка.

В данной теме обсуждаются исключительно динамически типизированные языки.

К примеру в JavaScript есть два значения похожих на `nil`: `null` и `undefined`. (Нужно ли было плодить?)

В Scheme есть `#f`, но нет `nil`. В [Factor](http://factorcode.org) тоже нету `nil`, и используют `f`. (Нужен ли `nil` если есть `false`?)

Кроме того, как-то читал что вроде в первых версиях Objective-C был объект `nil` (Objective-C не знаю вообще), который поглощал вызовы, был чёрной дырой. Т.е. вёл себя как NaN для чисел. На любое сообщение объект возвращал `nil`.

Насколько допустимо трактовать "пустые" объекты (пустой список, пустой словарь и т.д.) как `false`, и есть ли у такой фичи опасные побочные эффекты, или вообще расположение к каким-либо багам.

Приветствуются:

- Ссылки на статьи с обзором различных подходов
- Ссылки на какие-либо интересные языки, относящиеся к теме
- Обсуждение различных подходов, удобства и опасности использования

Comment: Этот вопрос связан с http://hashcode.ru/questions/10778 но отличается

Comment: <i>Насколько допустимо трактовать "пустые" объекты ... как false</i><br/>
Настолько, насколько актуален редкостный бред

Comment: Ну, вообще да, туповато. Просто вспомнился лисповый `(if () 'true 'false) => 'false`, тоже случай для рассмотрения.

Comment: Ну, то есть есть случаи, когда это удобно. Но обычно это опасно. В том же JavaScript сколько раз я попадался на всяких неожиданных "совпадениях", да ещё в разных браузерах.. красота просто эти "умные" интерпретаторы :)

Comment: @Vladimir VG, вы еще гляньте на Scala - ужаснетесь )

В ней мирно уживаются `Null, null, Nil, Nothing, None`. И все это разные вещи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NULL нужен там, где есть ссылки. Почему в JavaScript есть еще undefined? Потому что null и undefined - разные объекты. По умолчанию ссылка указывает на undefined, а null - элемент логики. Сейчас ссылка null, потом не null. Скажем так, в С/С++ указатели тоже не null изначально, а undefined.

Пустые объекты - не false, потому что false - семантическое значение. Элемент логических выражений, а null - нет (несмотря на то, что он используется в них, он преобразовывается).

Если кратко, то наличие пустого объекта обязательно для языков со ссылками, а false - это отдельный объект, такой же как строка "ABC" или 4 - т.е. непустой, а семантически значимый.

Comment: А если исключить null и вместо него использовать false для тех же целей. Никакой путаницы не возникнет.

Comment: Или наоборот, убрать `false` и использовать `null` для всех `!true` значений

Comment: Можно и так, но может возникнуть такая коллизия (на псевдоязыке):
var p = false;
var q = p;
// ...
if (q) { /* то что это значит? */ }

Comment: К тому же если говорить о списках. Есть пустое множество null, а есть множество из пустого множества [null] и это разные множества. Как ординальные числа. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Порядковое_число

Answer (score 4):

Хотя автор и задает вопрос по смыслу `nil/null` по отношению к динамическим языкам, но я считаю, что наиболее ярко смысл `NULL` раскрывается в SQL, а именно в случае со связанными запросами: пресловутые inner/left/right join). Без понятия NULL (то есть нет данных) весь SQL сильно теряет, если не сказать большего - вообще невозможно становится работать без `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что использование NULL важно в процессе отладки программы (скрипта). false - это все же нормальное значение переменной, а вот NULL - это именно отсутствие какого либо значения, вернее оно ПУСТОЕ. Обращение к NULL переменной может вызвать определенные исключительные ситуации, которые всегда вызовут ошибку работы программы, и именно это дает возможность легко найти и устранить эти ошибки.
Я всегда использую именно NULL, как при возврате значений из функций, так и при передаче значений в функцию. Проверяю не просто !переменная, а именно == != NULL... 
На мой взгляд так красивее ))
Удачи в поисках ответов!

Comment: Плюс, дополню, очень удобно использовать в SQL.
Например поле "дата выполнения" чего либо. Либо NULL - не выполнено, либо конкретная дата выполнения. Одновременно и флаг и значение.